# Using $this when not in object context while using destroy function

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my login and logout function in controller of a same page. When i use Session::destroy() in logout, it throws me an error "Using $this when not in object context". And also tell me how do i check session is active or not.
Thank you in advance

```
public function login(){
       $session = $this->request->session();  
      $student12 = TableRegistry::get('users');    
         $email=$this->request->data('email');
         $password=$this->request->data('password');
          $query12 = $student12->find();
          $query12->where(['email'=>$email]);
        foreach($query12 as  $datax)
        {
        if($datax['password']===$password&&$datax['email']===$email)
        {   

//Session::write($key, $value);
//Session::read($key);
         $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Panal','action' => 'Home']);
        }else{
          $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Student','action' => 'index']);  
        }
    }
    }

    public function logout(){

      Session::destroy();
       $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Panal','action' => 'Home']);

    }
```

Comment: You should use Cakephp Auth component for authentication. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

Comment: how to select table for auth

Comment: by default, Auth component uses table "users" with credential fields username and password. You can override this. To know more you must read the documentation and this tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html). It is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would like to use a different model than the `Users` model that CakePHP 3 defaults, you can put this in the settings of the `AuthComponent`.

```
// AppController.php -> initialize method
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Members']
]);
```

RTFM ref: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers